# Script to extract links from page and check the domain

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a script that iterates through a list of web pages, extracts the links from each page and checks each link to see if the are in a given set of domains. I have the script set up to write two files - pages with links in the given domains are written to one file while the rest are written to the other. I'm essentially trying to sort the pages based on the links in the pages. Below is my script but it doesn't look right. I'd appreciate any pointers to achieve this (I'm new at this, can you tell)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


urls = ['https://www.rose.com', 'https://www.pink.com']
for i in range(len(urls)):
    grab = requests.get(urls[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')
    f = open('links_good.txt', 'w')
    g = open('links_need_update.txt', 'w')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        data = link.get('href')
        check_url = re.compile(r'(www.x.com)+ | (www.y.com)')
        invalid = check_url.search(data)
        if invalid == None
            g.write(urls[i])
            g.write('\n')
        else:
            f.write(urls[i])
            f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly does not work quite right. Do you get urls in the files? Are some missing? What is the problem?

Comment: After making the changes suggested by @Grismar I tried for example running the script with some [amazon.com](http://amazon.com) pages in `urls` and tried to search for [google.com](http://google.com) or [facebook.com](http://facebook.com) links using `re.compile`. The script runs forever, I have to interrupt it with `Ctrl+C` and all the links in urls are written to the `links_need_update.txt` file

Comment: you should simplify your code and use this site to ask one specific question about single problem. It is not goot place for "please debug my code" type of questions. This types of questions are usually removed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some very basic problems with your code:

- `if invalid == None` is missing a `:` at the end, but should also be `if invalid is None:`
- not all `<a>` elements will have an `href`, so you need to deal with those, or your script will fail.
- the regex has some issues (you probably don't want to repeat that first URL and the parentheses are pointless)
- you write the URL to the file every time you find a problem, but you only need to write it to the file if it has a problem at all; or perhaps you wanted a full lists of all the problematic links?
- you rewrite the files on every iteration of your `for` loop, so you only get the final result

Fixing all that (and using a few arbitrary URLs that work):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


urls = ['https://www.gamespot.com', 'https://www.pcgamer.com']
f = open('links_good.txt', 'w')
g = open('links_need_update.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(urls)):
    grab = requests.get(urls[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        data = link.get('href')
        if data is not None:
            check_url = re.compile('gamespot.com|pcgamer.com')
            result = check_url.search(data)
            if result is None:
                # if there's no result, the link doesn't match what we need, so write it and stop searching
                g.write(urls[i])
                g.write('\n')
                break
    else:
        f.write(urls[i])
        f.write('\n')
```

However, there's still a lot of issues:

- you open file handles, but never close them, use `with` instead
- you loop over a list using an index, that's not needed, loop over `urls` directly
- you compile a regex for efficieny, but do so on every iteration, countering the effect

The same code with those problems fixed:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


urls = ['https://www.gamespot.com', 'https://www.pcgamer.com']
with open('links_good.txt', 'w') as f, open('links_need_update.txt', 'w') as g:
    check_url = re.compile('gamespot.com|pcgamer.com')
    for url in urls:
        grab = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            data = link.get('href')
            if data is not None:
                result = check_url.search(data)
                if result is None:
                    # if there's no result, the link doesn't match what we need, so write it and stop searching
                    g.write(url)
                    g.write('\n')
                    break
        else:
            f.write(url)
            f.write('\n')
```

Or, if you want to list all the problematic URLs on the sites:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


urls = ['https://www.gamespot.com', 'https://www.pcgamer.com']
with open('links_good.txt', 'w') as f, open('links_need_update.txt', 'w') as g:
    check_url = re.compile('gamespot.com|pcgamer.com')
    for url in urls:
        grab = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')
        good = True
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            data = link.get('href')
            if data is not None:
                result = check_url.search(data)
                if result is None:
                    g.write(f'{url},{data}\n')
                    good = False
    if good:
        f.write(url)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out my errors. This was super helpful. I'm still having difficulty running the script though. What I did for example was to try running the script with some amazon.com pages in urls and tried to search for google.com or facebook.com links using re.compile. The script runs forever, I have to interrupt it with Ctrl+C and all the links in urls are written to the links_need_update.txt file